# C fscanf returning the wrong value

Tags: c

I'm really stuck on something.

I have a text file, which has 1 word followed by ~100 float numbers. The float numbers are separated by space, tab, or newline. This format repeats several times throughout the text file.

For example, this is what the text file looks like:

```
one 0.00591 0.07272 -0.78274 ... 
0.0673 ...
0.0897 ...
two 0.0654 ...
0.07843 ...
0.0873 ...
three ...
...
...
```

This is a snippet of my code:

```
char word[30];
double a[1000];
double j;

while (!feof(fp))
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%s", word);
        printf("%s\n", word);
        while (!feof(fp) && (fscanf(fp, " %lf", &j)) == 1)
        {
            a[z] = j;
            z++;
            num_of_vectors++;
        }
        z = 0;
    }
```

The word "nine" in the text file, is printed as "ne".
And the word "in" doesn't even print, a floating point number gets printed.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Check the result value of `fscanf(fp, "%s", word) ==1` before using `word` in `printf("%s\n", word);`

Comment: Can we see the type declarations for word, a and j?

Comment: See [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) for information on why your outer loop is wrong.  You need to test the result of `fscanf()` — either instead of, or as well as, the result of `feof()`, but testing the result of `fscanf()` is usually sufficient.

Comment: Note, too, that your inner loop goes infinite when `fscanf()` encounters EOF.  Because EOF is not zero, the `while (fscanf(…))` loop will continue indefinitely — until you crash because you aren't checking the array bounds in that loop.  The lack of bounds checking could also be why you get the segmentation fault.  A better check for the inner loop would be `while (fscanf(…) == 1)`; the will stop both when a word is encountered and on EOF, and will continue while there are numbers to read.

Comment: I tried adding the fscanf == 1 && !feof checks, and that got rid of the Segmentation Fault, so thank you. But fscanf still returns the incorrect value for 2 words, "nine" gets printed as "ne", and instead of "in" I get a floating point number

Comment: Checking the result of `fscanf(fp, " %lf", &j) == 1`?  Does `j` have the value of infinity?  (Note "ni" are 2 letters of "inf")

Comment: Recommend to instead read lines of text and see if first "word/number" is indeed a word or `double`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the standard:

> An input item is defined as the longest sequence of input characters which does not exceed any specified field width and which is, or is a prefix of, a matching input sequence.

The likely reason that `nine` is giving you `ne` is because, when reading a double value, `nan` is one of the acceptable values. Hence, the `n` and `i` are read to establish that it's *not* `nan`.

Similarly, with the word `in`, that a valid prefix for `inf` representing infinity.

The standard also states in a footnote:

> fscanf pushes back ***at most*** one input character onto the input stream.

so it's quite possible that this is why the `i` in `nine` is not being pushed back.

Bottom line is that it's basically unsafe to assume where the file pointer will end up when `fscanf` operations fail for some reason.

---

One way to fix this is to use `ftell` and `fseek` to save the file pointer for each successfully item, so that you can move back to the correct file position if the thing you're attempting to read is *not* successful.

Let's say you have the input file:

```
one 1 2 3 4 5
nine 9 8 7 6 5
in 3.14159 2.71828
```

The following code will save and restore file positions to make it work as you wish:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char buff[50]; double dbl; size_t pos;
    FILE *fin = fopen("inputFile.txt", "r");
    while (fscanf(fin, "%s", buff) == 1) {
        printf("Got string [%s]\n", buff);
        pos = ftell(fin);
        while (sscanf(buff, "%lf", &dbl) == 1) {
            printf("Got double [%f]\n", dbl);
            pos = ftell(fin);
        }
        fseek(fin, pos, SEEK_SET);
    }
    fclose(fin);
    return 0;
}
```

By *commenting out* the `fseek`, you can see similar behaviour to what you describe:

```
Got string [one]
Got double [1.000000]
Got double [2.000000]
Got double [3.000000]
Got double [4.000000]
Got double [5.000000]
Got string [ne]
Got double [9.000000]
Got double [8.000000]
Got double [7.000000]
Got double [6.000000]
Got double [5.000000]
Got double [3.141590]
Got double [2.718280]
```

I consider this solution a little messy in that it's continuously having to call `ftell` and occasionally `fseek` to get it to work.

---

Another way is to just read *everything* as strings and decide whether it's a numeric or string with a `sscanf` operation after reading it in, as in the following code (with the afore-mentioned input file):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char buff[50]; double dbl;
    FILE *fin = fopen("inputFile.txt", "r");
    while (fscanf(fin, "%s", buff) == 1) {
        if (sscanf(buff, "%lf", &dbl) == 1) {
            printf("Got double [%f]\n", dbl);
        } else {
            printf("Got string [%s]\n", buff);
        }
    }
    fclose(fin);
    return 0;
}
```

This works because a floating point value is actually a proper subset of a string (i.e., it has no embedded spaces).

---

The output of both those programs above is:

```
Got string [one]
Got double [1.000000]
Got double [2.000000]
Got double [3.000000]
Got double [4.000000]
Got double [5.000000]
Got string [nine]
Got double [9.000000]
Got double [8.000000]
Got double [7.000000]
Got double [6.000000]
Got double [5.000000]
Got string [in]
Got double [3.141590]
Got double [2.718280]
```

which is basically what was desired.

---

One thing you need to be aware of is that scanning something like `inf` or `nan` as a double will actually work - that is the intended behaviour of the library (and how your original code would have worked had it not had the issues). If that's not acceptable, you can do something like evaluate the string *before* trying to scan it as a double, to ensure it's not one of those special values.

Comment: Thank you very much! I used the sscanf method and it printed all words. Thanks again!

Comment: This solution is not completely satisfactory: it is questionable whether a line starting with `inf` should be parsed as a number instead of a string. The file format needs to be more precisely specified.

Comment: @chqrlie, I could understand that comment if it *was* specced that `inf` should be processed as a string but, given it will now work as per the original (where `inf` would be scanned as a floating value), and that the OP accepted the answer, I have to disagree. However, I'll make a note of it to ensure no-one gets bitten by the behaviour.

Comment: Well, `inf` other than the first word of the file, of course. That would still be scanned as a string in the original.